# Select in JQ from Redfish Output

Tags: jq

I have data I'm getting back from an iLO interface using the Redfish API about the disks on the server.  I get a JSON similar to:

```
{
  "Server": "my-pc.org",
  "ArrayController": "DE0080000",
  "Health": "OK",
  "NumDrives": "2",
  "Drives": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Storage/DE0080000/Drives/0",
      "@odata.type": "#Drive.v1_14_0.Drive",
      "Id": "0",
      "Name": "15TB 22.5G SAS SSD",
      "Status": {
        "State": "UnavailableOffline",
        "Health": "Critical"
      },
      "LocationIndicatorActive": false,
      "Model": "VO001920RZWUV",
      "Revision": "HPD0",
      "Protocol": "SAS",
      "MediaType": "SSD",
      "CapacityBytes": 1920383410176,
      "BlockSizeBytes": 512,
      "SerialNumber": "12BA08LTL08",
      "FailurePredicted": false,
      "PredictedMediaLifeLeftPercent": 100,
      "StatusIndicator": "Fail",
      "Identifiers": [
        {
          "DurableName": "58CE38EE21D51FE",
          "DurableNameFormat": "NAA"
        }
      ],
      "PhysicalLocation": {
        "PartLocation": {
          "LocationType": "Bay",
          "ServiceLabel": "Slot=1:Port=2E:Box=1:Bay=1",
          "LocationOrdinalValue": 1
        }
      },
      "HotspareType": "None",
      "EncryptionAbility": "None",
      "WriteCacheEnabled": false,
      "CapableSpeedGbs": 22.5,
      "NegotiatedSpeedGbs": 12,
      "Operations": [],
      "Multipath": true,
      "Links": {
        "Volumes@odata.count": 1,
        "Volumes": [
          {
            "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Storage/DE0080000/Volumes/1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "@odata.etag": "\"63838C5C\""
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Storage/DE0080000/Drives/1",
      "@odata.type": "#Drive.v1_14_0.Drive",
      "Id": "1",
      "Name": "15TB 22.5G SAS SSD",
      "Status": {
        "State": "Enabled",
        "Health": "OK"
      },
      "LocationIndicatorActive": false,
      "Model": "VO001920RZWUV",
      "Revision": "HPD0",
      "Protocol": "SAS",
      "MediaType": "SSD",
      "CapacityBytes": 1920383410176,
      "BlockSizeBytes": 512,
      "SerialNumber": "12BA08LTL08",
      "FailurePredicted": false,
      "PredictedMediaLifeLeftPercent": 100,
      "StatusIndicator": "OK",
      "Identifiers": [
        {
          "DurableName": "58CE38EE21D51FE",
          "DurableNameFormat": "NAA"
        }
      ],
      "PhysicalLocation": {
        "PartLocation": {
          "LocationType": "Bay",
          "ServiceLabel": "Slot=1:Port=2E:Box=1:Bay=2",
          "LocationOrdinalValue": 2
        }
      },
      "HotspareType": "None",
      "EncryptionAbility": "None",
      "WriteCacheEnabled": false,
      "CapableSpeedGbs": 22.5,
      "NegotiatedSpeedGbs": 12,
      "Operations": [],
      "Multipath": true,
      "Links": {
        "Volumes@odata.count": 1,
        "Volumes": [
          {
            "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Storage/DE0080000/Volumes/1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "@odata.etag": "\"6383FE34\""
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to just pick out the ones that have "StatusIndicator" set to "Fail" and print out the .PhysicalLocation.PartLocation.ServiceLabel.  I tried:

```
jq -r '.Drives[] | select(.StatusIndicator=="Fail") | .PhysicalLocation.PartLocation.ServiceLabel' json-file
```

but I get nothing.  Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your sample [just works fine](https://jqplay.org/s/5eQrhyEXlZY).

Comment: Hmmm. Check for DOS line endings with `cat -vet file | head -5` if you see `^M$` at the end of each line, `dos2unix file` (but for all I know `jq` can deal with `\r\n` strings). Good luck.

Comment: No DOS line endings.  This is run on a RHEL 8 system.
When I run just:
```
jq -r '.Drives[]' json-file
```
I get something that is not a proper JSON.  It is a bunch of JSON's just concatenated together.  It is just too large an output to re-type here.  There are 7 array controllers.  Most of 10-14 drives each.

Comment: @user2664304 `jq -r '.Drives[]' json-file` [should](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-object-value-iterator) (and indeed [does](https://jqplay.org/s/EJ4J59W_ar_9)) produce "a bunch of JSON's just concatenated together". That's a stream of items found in the `.Drives` array, iterated over. With the other command, you then `select` (i.e. filter) for some criteria, then further traverse down into the structrure of those that survived the filter. The string(s) reached this way (`Slot=1:Port=2E:Box=1:Bay=1` in this case) is what will be output (and decoded first with the `-r` flag present).

Comment: @user2664304 Your filter works fine and will print all service labels. What is your expected output?